# Is there an option to make Microsoft Safety Scanner ask before removing what it thinks is malware?

Tags: windows, malware, anti-malware

Is there an option to make Microsoft Safety Scanner [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/intelligence/safety-scanner-download?view=o365-worldwide) ask before removing what it thinks is malware?

It looks like it might try to remove what it thinks is malware immediately and without asking, rather than listing what it thinks is malware and giving the option to remove it.

Comment: What options do you see when running `msert /?`

Comment: @harrymc great answer, thanks, you can post that as an answer and i'll accept it  https://i.imgur.com/NpunYhd.png

Comment: @harrymc just updated my comment replying to you, with an image link you can use in your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `msert /?` has shown these options :

[image]

The answer is then : `msert /N`, for detect-only mode.